# Jquery cannot $.ajax second link via ajax

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am having the following code on a one page site:

```
    <section class="block" id="panel1">
    </section>
    <section class="block" id="panel2">
    <div class="loadcontent">
    <div class="vcard">
    [content here]
    <a href="detail1.html">Proceed to detail level1</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="block" id="panel3">
    <div class="loadcontent">
    <div class="vcard">
    [content here]
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

The jquery I am using is this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
                $(".loadcontent").on("click","a",function(ev) {                   
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var $el = $(this);
                    var $lc = $el.closest(".loadcontent");
                    URLtarget = $el.attr("href");

                    //alert("URL:"+URLtarget+"\nZIndex:"+zindex+"\nATTR:"+$el.className);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: URLtarget, 
                        data: {},
                        type: 'post',
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $lc.find(".vcard").fadeOut(1000,function() {                                
                            });                             
                            $lc.append(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
});
```

On `detail1.html` I have the following code:

```
    <div class="vcard">
    <div><a href="#" class="closeme"> &times; CLOSE </a></div>
    [content here]
    <a href="detail2.html">Proceed to detail level1</a>
    </div>
```

And on `detail2.html` Is the same as detail1 but with different content template (and data). When I fire up the first link, it works ok loads the detail1.html but when I click inside detail1.html for detail2.html it leads to new page (ajax not working). I thought that the $.on() was "listening" for every appended event on the dom, what is the correct approach?

Also I tried to use another .on for `.closeme` link but it doesn't work, it leads me to the top of the document.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: As a suggestion, you don't always have to use a delegated event handler; you can directly add a new event handler to your new elements after they are inserted into the dom.

Comment: That is true, but I am generating the <section> block, depending on whether they have links or not (second/third/fourth level), this is the pure html example that I am using as a blueprint, and I was hoping to have a global solution and not making one for each section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating the the `<section>` block, then your event handler will not be set for them. Remember, when you use `on` to delegate, if can only attach an event handler *to an element that currently exists in the DOM*. Just use `$(document).on()` if you don't know what elements will be added.

Comment: Thanks, I just found it, but you get the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

So actually I found the answer, it was asked differently here on SO.

Instead of `$(_selector_).on("click","a",function() { ... });`
it needs `$(document).on("click","_selector_ a",function() { ... });`